# How to count entries in a mysql table grouped by time

Tags: mysql, group-by

I've found lots of not quite the answers to this question, but nothing I can base my rather limited sql skills on...

I've got a gas meter, which gives a pulse every cm3 of gas used - the time the pulses happen is obtained by a pi and stored in a mysql db. I'm trying to graph the db. In order to graph the data, I want to sum how many pulses are received every n time period. Where n may be 5 mins for a graph covering a day or n may be up to 24hours for a graph covering a year.

The data are in a table which has two columns, a primary key/auto inc called "pulse_ref" and "pulse_time" which stores a unix timestamp of the time a pulse was received.

Can anyone suggest a sql query to count how many pulses occurred grouped up into, say, 5minutely intervals?

Create table:

```
  CREATE TABLE `gas_pulse` (
    `pulse_ref` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `pulse_time` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`pulse_ref`));
```

Populate some data:

```
INSERT INTO `gas_pulse` VALUES (1,1477978978),(2,1477978984),(3,1477978990),(4,1477978993),(5,1477979016),(6,1477979063),(7,1477979111),(8,1477979147),(9,1477979173),(10,1477979195),(11,1477979214),(12,1477979232),(13,1477979249),(14,1477979267),(15,1477979285),(16,1477979302),(17,1477979320),(18,1477979337),(19,1477979355),(20,1477979372),(21,1477979390),(22,1477979408),(23,1477979425),(24,1477979443),(25,1477979461),(26,1477979479),(27,1477979497),(28,1477979515),(29,1477979533),(30,1477979551),(31,1477979568),(32,1477979586),(33,1477980142),(34,1477980166),(35,1477981433),(36,1477981474),(37,1477981526),(38,1477981569),(39,1477981602),(40,1477981641),(41,1477981682),(42,1477981725),(43,1477981770),(44,1477981816),(45,1477981865),(46,1477981915),(47,1477981966),(48,1477982017),(49,1477982070),(50,1477982124),(51,1477982178),(52,1477982233),(53,1477988261),(54,1477988907),(55,1478001784),(56,1478001807),(57,1478002385),(58,1478002408),(59,1478002458),(60,1478002703),(61,1478002734),(62,1478002784),(63,1478002831),(64,1478002863),(65,1478002888),(66,1478002909),(67,1478002928),(68,1478002946),(69,1478002964),(70,1478002982),(71,1478003000),(72,1478003018),(73,1478003036),(74,1478003054),(75,1478003072),(76,1478003090),(77,1478003108),(78,1478003126),(79,1478003145),(80,1478003163),(81,1478003181),(82,1478003199),(83,1478003217),(84,1478003235),(85,1478003254),(86,1478003272),(87,1478003290),(88,1478003309),(89,1478003327),(90,1478003346),(91,1478003366),(92,1478003383),(93,1478003401),(94,1478003420),(95,1478003438),(96,1478003457),(97,1478003476),(98,1478003495),(99,1478003514),(100,1478003533),(101,1478003552),(102,1478003572),(103,1478003592),(104,1478003611),(105,1478003632),(106,1478003652),(107,1478003672),(108,1478003693),(109,1478003714),(110,1478003735),(111,1478003756),(112,1478003778),(113,1478003799),(114,1478003821),(115,1478003844),(116,1478003866),(117,1478003889),(118,1478003912),(119,1478003936),(120,1478003960),(121,1478003984),(122,1478004008),(123,1478004033),(124,1478004058),(125,1478004084),(126,1478004109),(127,1478004135),(128,1478004161),(129,1478004187),(130,1478004214),(131,1478004241),(132,1478004269),(133,1478004296),(134,1478004324),(135,1478004353),(136,1478004381),(137,1478004410),(138,1478004439),(139,1478004469),(140,1478004498),(141,1478004528),(142,1478004558),(143,1478004589),(144,1478004619),(145,1478004651),(146,1478004682),(147,1478004714),(148,1478004746),(149,1478004778),(150,1478004811),(151,1478004844),(152,1478004877),(153,1478004911),(154,1478004945),(155,1478004979),(156,1478005014),(157,1478005049),(158,1478005084),(159,1478005120),(160,1478005156),(161,1478005193),(162,1478005231),(163,1478005268),(164,1478005306),(165,1478005344),(166,1478005383),(167,1478005422),(168,1478005461),(169,1478005501),(170,1478005541),(171,1478005582),(172,1478005622),(173,1478005663),(174,1478005704),(175,1478005746),(176,1478005788),(177,1478005831),(178,1478005873),(179,1478005917),(180,1478005960),(181,1478006004),(182,1478006049),(183,1478006094),(184,1478006139),(185,1478006186),(186,1478006231),(187,1478006277),(188,1478010694),(189,1478010747),(190,1478010799),(191,1478010835),(192,1478010862),(193,1478010884),(194,1478010904),(195,1478010924),(196,1478010942),(197,1478010961),(198,1478010980),(199,1478010999),(200,1478011018),(201,1478011037),(202,1478011056),(203,1478011075),(204,1478011094),(205,1478011113),(206,1478011132),(207,1478011151),(208,1478011170),(209,1478011189),(210,1478011208),(211,1478011227),(212,1478011246),(213,1478011265),(214,1478011285),(215,1478011304),(216,1478011324),(217,1478011344),(218,1478011363),(219,1478011383),(220,1478011403),(221,1478011423),(222,1478011443),(223,1478011464),(224,1478011485),(225,1478011506),(226,1478011528),(227,1478011549),(228,1478011571),(229,1478011593),(230,1478011616),(231,1478011638),(232,1478011662),(233,1478011685),(234,1478011708),(235,1478011732),(236,1478011757),(237,1478011782),(238,1478011807),(239,1478011832),(240,1478011858),(241,1478011885),(242,1478011912),(243,1478011939),(244,1478011967),(245,1478011996),(246,1478012025),(247,1478012054),(248,1478012086),(249,1478012115),(250,1478012146),(251,1478012178),(252,1478012210),(253,1478012244),(254,1478012277),(255,1478012312),(256,1478012347),(257,1478012382),(258,1478012419),(259,1478012456),(260,1478012494),(261,1478012531),(262,1478012570),(263,1478012609),(264,1478012649),(265,1478012689),(266,1478012730),(267,1478012771),(268,1478012813),(269,1478012855),(270,1478012898),(271,1478012941),(272,1478012984),(273,1478013028),(274,1478013072),(275,1478013117),(276,1478013163),(277,1478013209),(278,1478013255),(279,1478013302),(280,1478013350),(281,1478013399),(282,1478013449),(283,1478013500),(284,1478013551),(285,1478013604),(286,1478013658),(287,1478013714),(288,1478013771),(289,1478013830),(290,1478013891),(291,1478013954),(292,1478014019),(293,1478014086),(294,1478014156),(295,1478014228),(296,1478014301),(297,1478014373),(298,1478014446),(299,1478014518),(300,1478014591),(301,1478014664),(302,1478014736),(303,1478014809),(304,1478014882),(305,1478015377),(306,1478015422),(307,1478015480),(308,1478015543),(309,1478015608),(310,1478015676),(311,1478015740),(312,1478015803),(313,1478015864),(314,1478015921),(315,1478015977),(316,1478016030),(317,1478016081),(318,1478016129),(319,1478016176);
```

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry the OP has made changes to question to make it little more clear with some sample data set.The question seems quite fair to me.But it doesn't get good attention yet.

Comment: @kiranmuralee yes, the op has completed 2 of the minimum 3 tasks required to make this question worthy of attention- so a step (or two) in the right direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you need to get the pulse count in n-minute (in your case 5 minutes) intervals. For achieving this, please try the following query

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS gas_pulse_count,
    FROM_UNIXTIME(pulse_time - MOD(pulse_time, 5 * 60)) from_time,
    FROM_UNIXTIME((pulse_time - MOD(pulse_time, 5 * 60)) + 5 * 60) to_time
FROM
    gas_pulse
GROUP BY from_time
```

Comment: This seems pretty close to what I want - is there any way to make it report counts of zero, rather than just not returning an entry for that time period?

Comment: @Fraser73 the from_time and to_time values depends on pulse_time data,so by above query we can't produce reports counts of zero for other time periods.But you could get over that manually in place where you draw your graph by plotting zero where no data is reported.